# Log-in to the Community as User from a Contact record issue

Tags: community

When I click on the Log-in to the Community as User' from Contact record, it redirects me to login page; Whereas I should be redirected to the Community Home page.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Has the user been activated in the community by clicking the link from the email sent when they were setup?

Comment: Do you have any custom login page for your community?

Comment: yes, I used to log-in via that option; but now it does not seem to work. @DaveHumm

Comment: yes, I do have a custom Login VF page @Reshma

Comment: Can you check is there any action method specified or post code here.

Comment: Are you the System Administrator in the SF Org? This previous question and answers may help http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34025/log-in-to-community-as-user